# Nested directives break angular

Tags: angularjs, nested, directive

Whenever I use a directive within itself, the page freezes, and eats up more and more CPU and RAM until the tab hangs.

What I have is this

```
Application.Directives.directive('somed', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        // Load the template from a separate HTML file
        templateUrl: 'directives/somed/view.html',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

and template like

```
<div ng-if="nonexistent">
    <somed></somed>
</div>
```

Which should *never* load the nested directive (the ng-if evaluates to false, so no content is shown. This is confirmed if I put a div tag instead of somed). Yet, the browser hangs on it.

How come, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: if `nonexistent` is ever truthy, then you'll end up with infinite recursive calls.  but you said `which should **never** load the nested directive`.  If you can guarantee that it `"never"` loads the nested directive, then why can't you just remove it entirely?

Comment: It's just for demo purposes, to show that somehow, a recursive loop exists, even though the directive should never be loaded. I agree that it could be removed altogether in its current form, but in the real application, it cannot :-)

Comment: I would think this would happen even without Angular, its like setting up a function in vanilla JS that uses a global variable that is always `true` to decide on whether or not to call itself.  Its not breaking Angular its doing what you're asking, the browser is just running out of memory executing the script and thus hanging.  Its just poor coding.

Comment: Except the global variable is always false. And yet, the browser hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of `ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf) says:

> Also, `ngIf` recreates elements using their compiled state.

And since template for `somed` references `somed`, it'll not be able to successfully compile.
That will explain the problem.

There are several ways of preventing it, depending on your needs.

1. You can include the `template` using an [`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) and putting the template in your [`$templateCache`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache).
2. You can dynamically set the `html` of the element on which this directive is being called in the `link` function and then use the [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service to interpret the (possibly recursive) directives inside it.

Comment: Correcto. The second solution works for me. Angular indeed compiles the templates before it uses them, and it wants to compile all the sub-directives as well, causing an infinite loop. I think they should then fallback to runtime-compiling, or at least trigger an error, and not crashing, but that's just me ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Its like doing this:

```
var iAmAlwaysTrue = true;

function test(){
    if(iAmAlwaysTrue)
        test();
} // end test

test();
```

Like I said in my comment its not breaking AngularJS its just poor coding.  If I did this in C++, is it breaking C++ or just bad code?

EDIT: If you were trying to prove that a recursive situation would exist, that AngularJS would identify the directive in the directive's own template then I'm guessing you succeeded given the outcome of your experiment, but its my guess that a test could have been avoided given that Angular's own directives `ng-?` are interpreted in a directive's template just fine - there's no reason directive's you create wouldn't also be.

Comment: Well, the one difference is that iAmAlwaysTrue = false; so that it actually should *never* recurse. Yet, it does, and it hangs.